# Quarkus - Code to implement different actions based on different timeout values

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

I have a requirement to call REST API and implement different actions based on response times. For example, if the response is less than 30 secs - do process A, if between 31 - 60 seconds - do process B and timeout after 60 seconds. Is there any sample code to implement this in Quarkus/Mutiny? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide some code since your question does not provide any details. It is because there are various libraries and solutions that you can use.

In general, I find it helpful to use a simple time diff method. This applies regardless of whether the code is implemented synchronously or asynchronously. The overall progress will be something like this:

1. Create a variable that stores the timestamp just before sending an HTTP request
2. Send the HTTP request
3. Retrieve the response and create a new timestamp, then compare it with the previous time.

When you compare these two timestamps you have the pending time between the request initiation and the resolution of its response.

By the way, If you have some base code that you desire to extend to achieve this functionality, please add it to the question and I might be able to edit it and show how the code may generally look like.